# Target Each DIV Individually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a div when the title is clicked. I came up with this

```
$( '.industrial-product' ).find('.show-features').click(function() {
    $('.industrial-product').find('.ip-features').toggle();
});
```

using the markup

```
<div class="industrial-product">
<a href="#" class="show-features"><h3>Title</h3></a>
<div class="ip-features">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae modi ex iste deleniti soluta esse recusandae eveniet deserunt animi, officia suscipit voluptatibus temporibus excepturi nemo quaerat eius sequi aut unde.
</div>
```

This does basically what I want which is to display the ip-features div when the title is clicked but this shows/hides all on the page. I have 8 products and all need to toggle individually. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be easy to do.  If I understand right you want to just show and hide the one that is clicked.  You need to target using $(this) since it is a sibling of the title go to its parent then find the title.

Try this:

*HTML*

```
<div class="industrial-product">
     <a href="#" class="show-features"><h3>Title</h3></a>
     <div class="ip-features">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae modi ex iste deleniti soluta esse recusandae eveniet deserunt animi, officia suscipit voluptatibus temporibus excepturi nemo quaerat eius sequi aut unde.
     </div>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
$( '.industrial-product' ).find('.show-features').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.ip-features').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$( '.industrial-product' ).each(function(){
  var $root = $(this);
  var $ip = $root.find('.ip-features');

  $root.find('.show-features').click(function() {
    $ip.toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why down vote without leaving a comment.  This answer looks good to me.  It is great practice to assign this to a variable.  Helps with scoping.  Please if you vote down a great answer like this, leave a comment.  That way everyone can learn.

Comment: I also did not see a reason to down vote this answer. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference the context of where the click occurred tp find the correct `.ip-features` div to hide:

```
$( '.industrial-product' ).find('.show-features').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.industrial-product').find('.ip-features').toggle();
});
```

Comment: should be `parents` (pural). I cannot believe so many people answered at the same time and no one got it right. (edit: works on this markup indeed, sorry, but that wasn't harder to answer the generic question)

Comment: parent works too.. http://api.jquery.com/parent/ `parents` is used when traversing more than one level up, looking for ancestors. Also, tons of people got workable anwers

Comment: You are right, I edited my message. however he may come back in two days after adding a div in between, which would be avoided using parents. In general, better be safe about your markup structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to target the specific element that was clicked, rather than all elements matching the selector.

```
$(".industrial-product").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".ip-features").toggle();
});
```

Also, you don't need to use `.each()` when using an event binding method. jQuery automatically applies it to all elements matching the selector (in general, jQuery does this whenever it makes sense).